# problem in opencart in Terms & Conditions popup

Tags: popup, opencart

I have a website built in OpenCart and have a problem in a popup when you add an element to Shopping cart and then click on checkout and you will see Terms & Conditions When you click on it, it will show you Popup But the text is unclear
how I can solve this problem[HomePage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gVZQv.png),[Terms & Conditions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AAszA.png),[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WSJ09.png),
link website:[website](https://noontekmarket.com)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the followig URL. There is the problem in scripting error to display inner code in content id. You can fix this issue, content will be set as per display box.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xA0zI.png